Emojis do not work properly with the Facebook API
Emojis sent through the Facebook API are not displayed correctly on Facebook.
This functionality used to work, but now, instead of emojis, the symbols “?” are displayed.
I tried using UNICODE, HTML code and shortcode.
The problem can be reproduced in the Graph API Explorer.
Link to the Graph API Explorer
For the test I used the following steps.

I took a Facebook profile ID.

GET /v20.0/me?fields=id,name

I created a video broadcast.

POST /v20.0/<USER_ID>/live_videos
status="LIVE_NOW"
title="Front "
description="Front "


After I started the broadcasting the Facebook post become visible.

After that, I made a request, using the broadcast ID, to receive the stream link.


The streaming link format as follows:
rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/FB-1013749643592269-0-AbzJB6nb_Z183JwA,
To get the streaming link I made the following request:
GET /v20.0/<LIVE_VIDEO_ID>

I started a broadcast in "OBS Studio" with that streaming link.

I ended up checking the post on Facebook.


Facebook SDK for PHP (v5)
I'm using Graph API Explorer v20
Creating a video broadcast.
Getting the streaming url and broadcast title.
Result on Facebook.
Documentation for creating a live broadcast.
